# Some problems with the configuration of the "Profile Conditionals" extension

Tags: custom-fields, extension, fields, admin, condition

I've created a profile to register **new contacts** from this page: https://crm.ingenium.org.mx/solicitud-de-admision/

The ID of this Profile is **"18"**. So, this profile uses some fields from a group of custom fields that have the ID **"11"** and the last question of this group is three radio button options: if option 1 has been selected another group of custom fields should be shown with the ID: **"13"** and if that option is not selected, the custom field group should be hidden.

I've added the following code to the end of my "civicrm.settings.php" file but I am not getting the results of the condition to the last button radio question:

```
global $civicrm_setting;
 $civicrm_setting['com.joineryhq.profcond']['com.joineryhq.profcond'] = 
  array(
  'custom_11' => array(
  'entity' => 'Contact',
  'field' => 'custom_117',
  'op' => '=',
  'value' => '1',
  'show' => array(
  'custom_13',
   ),
  ),
 );
```

[image]